# fullcalendar - date format for end/start events

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar, momentjs

This (I hope) is a basic question.  I'm not seeing calendar events in fullcalendar, and I believe the issue is the date format I am attempting to use for start/end events.  I am attempting to setup a basic calendar by loading JSON events.  Here is my JSON output (trimmed to one event so as not to take up much room):

```
[{"id":"89","title":"A Title","start":"June 2nd 2015","end":"August 14th 2015"}]
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: false,
        events: "data.php"
    });
});
```

Again, very basic.  I know for certain that the issue for the events not appearing is due to the date format I am using, but I am not certain how to tell fullCalendar to use the `MMMM Do YYYY` format for start/end events with moment.js.  Does anyone have advice on how this is accomplished?

EDIT:

Attempted to add something along these lines...but still no luck:

```
var start = moment(event.start).format("MMMM Do YYYY");
var end = moment(event.end).format("MMMM Do YYYY");
```

Comment: You could convert the dates on the json to a format that fullCalendar understands.

Comment: I could...and I will do that as a last resort.  But I'd rather use the `MMMM Do YYYY` format if possible.  If it's not possible, then I will go that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would be considered an answer or more of a workaround, but I'll post it as an answer anyway.

I ended up just converting the date format in the json output as Bruno had suggested in the above comment.  Sort of wished I could have figured it out with the javascripting, but after hours of trying I could never get the events to display in the calendar.

I'll go ahead and post my php source for those curious (just showing the start date):

```
    $start = $row['startdate'];
    $start_obj = new \DateTime($start);
    $events['start'] = $start_obj->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished something similar by defining a function for the events, iterating through the data creating `moment.js` objects for the `start` field using my desired format. The [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) have the basics for how to accomplish this.

EDIT: I copied the example from the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) and modified the start time using `moment.js`.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myxmlfeed.php',
        dataType: 'xml',
        data: {
            // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
            start: start.unix(),
            end: end.unix()
        },
        success: function(doc) {
            var events = [];
            $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                events.push({
                    title: $(this).attr('title'),
                    start: moment($(this).attr('start'), 'MMMM Do YYYY') // will be parsed
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: So I would create an event like this:
   `events: function(start, end) {`
       `data: {`
           `start: (MMMM Do YYYY),`
           `end: (MMMM Do YYYY)`
       `}`
Is that correct? (sorry, not sure how to do code format in comments)

Comment: Edited the answer with an example.  Please note that this example is not a drop in solution for you since the ajax call expects an XML result, not JSON, but this should be easy for you to change.

Comment: Still not getting it - tried various methods with moment.  I'll keep playing with it though.